How can I turn OFF "Automatically follow redirect" in Rest Assured/Java with GET requests?
I've been stuck on this for several weeks (I'm totally new to Rest Assured) and I need help from the community.
My problem is that I am trying to make a GET request to the oauth2/authorize endpoint, which I pass as parameters everything that I know that Oauth needs to authenticate.
The expected behavior when doing the GET is that the API returns a 302 code, and in the response header the Location parameter returned with the code that should be passed to the next request.
This behavior happens successfully in Postman, as long as in the configuration I have the "Automatically follow redirects. Follow HTTP 3xx responses as redirects." option DISABLED.
If I leave it checked, then nothing works, because I get a "504 Gateway" error.
I find this same error in Rest-Assured, since this Postman option that never allows redirection, I cannot recreate it in my Rest-Assured code. Redirection is always done and I would like help to avoid it.
How can I disable GET redirects in Rest Assured the same way it is done in Postman?
  given().log().all().
                    redirects().follow(false).
                    headers(headers).
                    pathParam("idClient", config.getProperty("idClient")).
                    pathParam("token", token).
                    pathParam("codeChallenge", config.getProperty("codeChallenge")).
                    pathParam("scope", config.getProperty("scope")).
                    pathParam("redirectURI", config.getProperty("redirectURI")).
                    pathParam("state", config.getProperty("state")).
                    when().
                    get(oAuthUrl + "{idClient}&code_challenge={codeChallenge}&code_challenge_method=S256&response_type=code&scope={scope}&redirect_uri={redirectURI}&csrf={token}&decision=allow&state={state}");

I have tried using redirects().follow(false). and other methods to avoid the redirect like .followRedirects(false), I have moved this rule between the given, when and then, I have tried trying to catch the 504 error and force it to be a 302... Nothing works. Can you help me? Thank you very much in advance.

Does this answer your question? Get the url of a redirect with Rest Assured?

No, this is not working for me.

RestAssured handles redirects just right. You can debug your solutions with the help of https://httpbin.org/
Test following redirects:
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String body = RestAssured
            .given()
            .redirects()
            .follow(true)
            .get("https://httpbin.org/redirect-to?url=https://httpbin.org/get")
            .body().asString();

    System.out.println(body);

}

will print:
{
  "args": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip,deflate", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "Apache-HttpClient/4.5.13 (Java/11.0.22)", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-6647bfce-45ba1d827e4f570f4491c613"
  }, 
  "origin": "31.134.139.220", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/get"
}


while:
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String targetLocation = RestAssured
            .given()
            .redirects()
            .follow(false)
            .get("https://httpbin.org/redirect-to?url=https://httpbin.org/get")
            .header("Location");

    System.out.println(targetLocation);

}

will print:
https://httpbin.org/get

which is exactly where you are redirected in my first example. This happens because you suppress redirection with .redirects().follow(false) and hence you can get headers of redirection response.
